# Extracting confidence intervals from lme model

Tags: r, confidence-interval, nlme

I have to make some transformations on the confidence intervals of multiple large models made with the `lme()` function from the `nlme` package. I'm using the `intervals()` function to get the intervals, however it is not possible to turn it into a dataframe. Is there any way I could turn this into accessable numbers?

```
library(nlme)
data(mtcars)
model = lme(mpg ~ disp + cyl, random=~1|gear,  data=mtcars)
CI<-intervals(model, which = "fixed")
Approximate 95% confidence intervals

 Fixed effects:
              lower        est.         upper
(Intercept) 29.43497446 34.66099475 39.8870150353
disp        -0.04163023 -0.02058363  0.0004629675
cyl         -3.04786061 -1.58727681 -0.1266930105
attr(,"label")
[1] "Fixed effects:"

data.frame(CI)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = 
stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"intervals.lme"’ to a data.frame
```

Comment: have a look at `str(CI)`, you will see it is a list. Try `data.frame(CI$fixed)`

Comment: Try to look here if you like the tidy approach https://github.com/bbolker/broom.mixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CI$fixed` to get the values, then storing in a data frame. E.g.

```
df <- data.frame(CI$fixed)
```